# (13)Permission denied: AH02611: create: apr_shm_create(/log/slotmem-shm-p24af65f1_0.shm) failed

Tags: httpd, httpd.conf, chroot

I updated httpd to version 2.4.57. I compiled httpd on my own and when I start httpd within a `chroot` environment, I am getting this error message in the logs:

```
[Thu Jun 22 14:33:27.319378 2023] [slotmem_shm:error] [pid 3591] (13)Permission denied: AH02611: create: apr_shm_create(/log/slotmem-shm-p24af65f1_0.shm) failed
[Thu Jun 22 14:33:27.319470 2023] [proxy_balancer:emerg] [pid 3591] (13)Permission denied: AH01179: balancer slotmem_create failed
[Thu Jun 22 14:33:27.319477 2023] [:emerg] [pid 3591] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
```

In my `httpd.conf` there is this part where I define the value of `DefaultRuntimeDir`:

```
<IfDefine !DEV>
DefaultRuntimeDir /log
</IfDefine>
```

And this are my rights on that directory:

```
drwxrwxrwx  4 web web     4096 Jun 22 13:32 log
```

What I am missing here?

**Edit**

I tried to trace with `strace` which files are accessed during startup of `httpd` (`open` and `write` events) and I found this line:

```
6579  open("/dev/shm/ShM.fc123de7H42c92a7", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC, 0644) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Checking the rights within my `chroot` environment of `/dev/shm` I get this output

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root        40 Jun 22 16:58 shm
```

But I am not sure if that is correct or what I can change here.

Comment: seems like apparme or selinux or just a out of path violation to me